# Drawing a tree without nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I redraw this without nodes and just having dots between arrows?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{petri}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=gray,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:$#1$,name=#1},
redarrow/.style={->, red, fill=none,>=stealth},bluearrow/.style={->, blue, fill=none,>=stealth},  
redline/.style={-,red,fill=none},blueline/.style={-,blue,fill=none}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state=a^{-1}]{};
\node[state=1,right=of a^{-1}]{};
\node[state=b,above=of 1]{};
\node[state=a,right=of 1]{};
\node[state=ab^{-1},above=of a]{};
\node[state=aa,right=of a]{};
\node[state=ac,below=of a]{};
\node[state=acc,right=of ac]{};
\node[state=aca,below =of ac]{};
\draw[redarrow](a^{-1})--(1);
\draw[redarrow](1)--(b);
\draw[redarrow](1)--(a);
\draw[redarrow](ab^{-1})--(a);
\draw[redarrow](a)--(aa);
\draw[redarrow](a)--(ac);
\draw[redarrow](ac)--(acc);
\draw[redarrow](ac)--(aca);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for but perhaps this is a start: you could simply name the nodes rather than specifying `state` and then use a style for every node to ensure each is a filled circle.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{petri}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=gray,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:$#1$,name=#1},
redarrow/.style={->, red, fill=none,>=stealth},bluearrow/.style={->, blue, fill=none,>=stealth},
redline/.style={-,red,fill=none},blueline/.style={-,blue,fill=none},
every node/.append style={circle, fill}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a^{-1}) {};
\node (1) [right=of a^{-1}]{};
\node (b) [above=of 1]{};
\node (a) [right=of 1]{};
\node (ab^{-1}) [above=of a]{};
\node (aa) [right=of a]{};
\node (ac) [below=of a]{};
\node (acc) [right=of ac]{};
\node (aca) [below =of ac]{};
\draw[redarrow](a^{-1})--(1);
\draw[redarrow](1)--(b);
\draw[redarrow](1)--(a);
\draw[redarrow](ab^{-1})--(a);
\draw[redarrow](a)--(aa);
\draw[redarrow](a)--(ac);
\draw[redarrow](ac)--(acc);
\draw[redarrow](ac)--(aca);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Contentless nodes]

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code with a `matrix`. It helps to position nodes and with `matrix of nodes` option it automatically add names to nodes: `matrix_name-row-column`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, fill=black, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm},
redarrow/.style={->, red, fill=none,>=stealth},
bluearrow/.style={->, blue, fill=none,>=stealth},
redline/.style={-, red, fill=none}, 
blueline/.style={-,blue,fill=none},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes={state}, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]
{&.&.&\\.&.&.&.\\&&.&.\\&&.&\\};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/2,2/3,3/4}
{
    \draw[redarrow] (A-2-\i)--(A-2-\j);
    \draw[redarrow] (A-\i-3)--(A-\j-3);
}
\draw[redarrow] (A-1-2)--(A-2-2);
\draw[redarrow] (A-3-3)--(A-3-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure abaut what you mean with `redraw without nodes` but in case you want to use hardcoded coordinates to place dots and draw arrows between see what happens:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw plot[mark=*, only marks] coordinates {(0,2) (1,2) (1,3) (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (3,1) (3,2)};

\foreach \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/3}
{
    \draw[redarrow] (\i,2)--(\j,2);
    \draw[redarrow,<-] (2,\i)--(2,\j);
}
\draw[redarrow] (1,3)--(1,2);
\draw[redarrow] (2,1)--(3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Using `nodes` command `draw[->] (A)--(B)` means draw an arrow between center of node A and center of node B but only between node borders while `draw[->] (0,0)--(0,1);` means draw an arrow between coordinates `(0,0)` and `(0,1)` without worring about what is drawn on these coordinates.